# How do I call c# method in javascript?

Tags: javascript, c#, master-pages

I need help, I want to call a method from c# code behind aspx in javascript. My code in javascript is not working in Site.Master. And I also can't fix my error: The name does not exist in the current context:

```js
  function SendNoResponse() {
  
     <%#btnCallCSFunction_Click() %>;
            }
```

Thank you!!

Comment: Don't know for sure if this might work:
Is the C# function binded to a button? Then you can select the button with Javascript (by adding a id to it) and trigger a click.

Comment: Web applications don't work like this... The javascript code is running on the client and the C# code is running on the server... You need to make an ajax call or post back... What are you using? Webforms? Asp.Mvc?

Comment: Depending on what it is the event function is supposed to do, you can mark the function with the `[WebMethod]` attribute, and make it `static`. Then you can make an `ajax` call easily enough.

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: I need this after the onload page. I have timeout function in javascript